# Ignore unavailable data in Python pie chart plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting pie chart with the following dataframe.
The data is adds up to 0.932 which is less than 1.
Accordingly, the pie plot is producing 'four' pies.

I want a pie plot without the unavailable(1-0.932) pie in the chart.
The plot should have 3 pies with 0.62, 0.31 and 0.02.
How to do it? Please suggest.

```
import pandas as pd
df99 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Perc': [0.62, 0.31, 0.02]})
df99.plot.pie(y='Perc')
```

Comment: Need to normalise by dividing "Perc" column by it's sum: ie sumthing like `df99.assign(normed_perc=(df99['Perc'] / df99['Perc'].sum())).plot.pie(y='normed_perc')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the sum is smaller than 1, `pie` draws an incomplete circle. So, you could multiply the numbers e.g. by 100. `pie` will calculate percentages that sum to 100; dividing and multiplying with the original sum gives back the original numbers.  Pandas `plot.pie`doesn't allow for a lot of fine tuning, so in thic case, directly calling matplotlib's `pie` could make things easier:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df99 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Perc': [0.62, 0.31, 0.02]})
plt.pie(df99['Perc']*100, labels=df99['Data'],
        autopct=lambda p: f"{p*df99['Perc'].sum()/100:.2f}")
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]